# ASP.NET MVC error : Object being referred to is not locked by any Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, azure

When ever we try to update a user using an ASP.net MVC4 website, we get this error. Please help me to find out . This was working previously without any issue.

`ErrorCode<ERRCA0012>:SubStatus<ES0001>`:Object being referred to is not locked by any client.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0012>:SubStatus<ES0001>:`Object being referred to is not locked by any client.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0012>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Object being referred to is not locked by any client.]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ErrStatus errStatus, Guid trackingId, Exception responseException, Byte[][] payload, EndpointID destination) +551
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.ExecuteApi(IVelocityRequestPacket request, IMonitoringListener listener) +287
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener) +360
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalPutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener) +216
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.<>c__DisplayClass9d.<PutAndUnlock>b__9c() +160
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout) +276
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<PutAndUnlock>b__1b() +52
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.<>c__DisplayClass31`1.<PerformCacheOperation>b__30() +19
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheRetryWrapper.PerformCacheOperation(Action action) +208
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PerformCacheOperation(Func`1 func) +167
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DataCacheForwarderBase.PutAndUnlock(String key, Object value, DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle, TimeSpan timeout) +162
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +929
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270
```

Comment: Please provide the source code of the method your executing rather than leaving us to have to deduce it from the stack trace.

Comment: Timing of your question couldn't be better because we're dealing with the exact same error right now ... Can you check if your requests are not timing out? See this post for more details: http://www.anujvarma.com/session-storage-app-fabric-cache/

Comment: Dear @GauravMantri <httpRuntime executionTimeout = "300"/> the line of code is not there in our web config. Does it means that I need to add otherwise it takes the default?

Comment: We tried that and seemingly that didn't really help us. Please check your code and see if there's anything there which would cause the requests to timeout. In our case, it was the retry policy we have set for retrying storage operations.

Comment: We're getting the exact same problem in azure too, brought us down today.  It resolved after some rebooting and bringing up additional servers.  We have no code that runs on session end so I'm not sure if we're just putting something into session that we shouldn't be or if there is just a bug / problem with the azure caching session provider.

Comment: We do have a time consuming re indexing going on, however I was trying to do that as an asynchronous way. However that too not helping here. Will keep you posted. And again @GauravMantri your solution did help me to get rid of the error however the updating is too slow it is taking at least 3 to 4 minutes to complete an update operation. I will post how we are progressing.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks a lot adding `<httpRuntime executionTimeout = "300"/>` solved our issue. Please add this as answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check if your requests are not timing out. We also faced exact same issue in our project and we found this blog post really helpful in finding why we were running into this issue: http://www.anujvarma.com/session-storage-app-fabric-cache/.

One thing we initially did was increased the request timeout to 5 minutes (300 seconds) in web.config as mentioned in the blog post. However we only did it for the action where we knew we would encounter the timeout issue. To change the timeout for all actions, you could do something like below which was mentioned in the post:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout = "300"/>
  </system.web>
```

Or you could do is increase the timeout for specific action:

```
  <location path="Controller/Action">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

IMHO, 2nd option is more preferable over the 1st one because you're targeting specific actions instead of your entire site.

However as mentioned in my comments as well, this is not really foolproof. Better alternative would be to optimize the code first so that your requests are not taking long time. In our case, we had a bad retry policy for storage operations and we fixed the issue by modifying that retry policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried with the first option and it solved our issue. Though the second option looks more viable, let me try with that too. Finally thanks for helping out.

Comment: this happens a lot to me when I step through code to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but this is a workaround to make sure this error doesn't take down your instance.  It catches the error and then resets the cache instance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/04/29/cache-retry-fails-what-next.aspx

You catch the exception, check if it's a datacache exception, then reset the cache settings.

```
    public static void Refresh()
    {
        var factory = _factory; if (factory != null)
        {
            factory.Dispose();
            _factory = null;
        }
        _cache = null;

        DataCacheFactory.Reinitialize();
        DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.Reinitialize();
    }
```